# Sort dataframe given list order Python

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

i have a dataframe with a row containing first names of people.
Now i want to sort the dataframe on name but not on alphabetical order but on a given order. So for example I want to order my dataframe on row of names in the order:

```
L = ['marc','paul','beck','julia','rest']
```

If I have a dataframe containing a row with names I want the marc's at the top and then paul's, beck's etc.

How can i do this time efficient in python?

Comment: Can you share a sample of the dataframe?

Comment: This is just an example but the row  containing the names looks like ['paul','paul','julia','marc','paul','beck','beck','julia']

Answer (score 2):

If need reorder data by column convert all values to [ordered categoricals](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/categorical.html), so possible [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['paul','paul','julia','marc','paul','beck','beck','julia']})

L = ['marc','paul','beck','julia','rest']

df['A'] = pd.CategoricalIndex(df['A'], ordered=True, categories=L)

df = df.sort_values('A')
print (df)
       A
3   marc
0   paul
1   paul
4   paul
5   beck
6   beck
2  julia
7  julia
```

Answer (score 1):

```
L = ['marc','paul','beck','julia','rest']
df=pd.DataFrame()
df['L']=L
```

This gives you:

```
    L
0   marc
1   paul
2   beck
3   julia
4   rest
```

marc paul beck, in the right order.

Comment: then I just assign new values to the row, but it is a dataframe that I want to order on the given names